# Display value form rows marked in spotfire visualization?

Tags: javascript, ironpython, spotfire

After marking in a visualization i want to capture a particular column value form rows marked and display it in text area .

thanks

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow, please have a look here before posting: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to add a data function to the analysis. Define the function as a identity function, i.e.:

```
output <- input
```

This can be an R function or TERR function. If you use TERR it can execute locally rather than going to stat services (though web player will need to use stat services anyway).

Now, connect the data function to your analysis and as input you make it depend on the current marking. Assign a value to the input parameter by creating an aggregation on the column with the value you are looking to collect.
Assign the output of the data function to a document property.

The image linked here shows a sample of how to configure the input parameter:
[Sample input parameter config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpvNa.png)

To show the result in the text area you create a normal property control of your choice in the text area, and attach it to the document property that is written to by the R/TERR script.